# If I claim a dependent who owes back taxes, is my refund at risk?

Tags: united-states, irs, income-tax-refund, dependents

He has had his "refund" confiscated by the IRS in past years to pay back taxes, but didn't make any money last year.

He lived with me for the entire year.

I want to claim him as a dependent on my return this year to potentially increase my own return, but am wondering if this amount he has in arrears could affect my refund in any way.

Comment: What is the relationship between you and this person?

Comment: The dependent is my son.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only responsible for IRS debt that you owe from returns that you have filed for yourself. The back taxes that your dependent owes are between him and the IRS.